# delete specific value in column Realm Database

Tags: android, sqlite, realm

Can I delete a value from a column in realm database?

Like this in sqlite:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

I tried the `RealmResults` `remove` method but it's only taking a position or an object.

For example, I want to delete "A" in alphabet column from table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for the data that you want deleted and then call `deleteAllFromRealm` on the result. Like so

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.where(Foo.class).equalTo("fieldName", "value").findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: thanks
i think that will work,but i don't see `deleteAllFromRealm`.
 i use 0.87.5 version